# how to fix java code visual structure

Tags: java, code-readability

I have java code that isn't visually structured properly, all the code ~1000 words is all on a single line.

Is there a way to fix the structure where the functions and the spacing for sub functions are formatted visually ...?

Thanks,

Comment: If you are using Eclipse use ctrl+shift+F to format the code

Comment: Which IDE do you have in use?

Comment: @Algorithmist That should be the answer.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid programming question. It is in no way a matter of opinion. There's no reason to close this. Leave it open.

Comment: @Ethan Agreed. This would be a matter of opinion if the OP was requesting the best way to make his code look beautiful, or the best way to organize the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different IDEs have different shortcuts to reformat code. If you're using:

Netbeans - Ctrl + Shift + F. 
Eclipse - Ctrl + A to highlight all code, and Ctrl + I to indent it. Or you could just hold down Ctrl + Shift + F

Edit: Check [this](http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipseide/source_formatting/) out if my answer was not sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You also able to use this online formatter:

[PrettyPrinter](http://www.prettyprinter.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the editor you're using. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, there will be a "code cleanup" function, which will attempt to format your code to the current preferences.

If you're using vi or emacs - not so much, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

[**Jalopy**](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/jalopy/manual.html) is a source code formatter for the Sun Java programming language.

It layouts any valid Java source code according to some widely configurable rules; to meet a certain coding style without putting a formatting burden on individual developers.

**Jalopy's functionality covers:**

```
- Brace style transformation
- Fine-grained white space settings
- Indentation
- Intelligent line wrapping
- Code separation
- Javadoc auto-generation
- Header/Footer templates
- Powerful command-line interface
- Several Plug-ins
```

Comment: It would be better if you can suggest how to use this?

Comment: To use it you need to install it's plugin based on your need. For example link contain installation and integration of eclipse plugin. 
http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/existing/plugin-eclipse.html

Available plugins are Jalopy-Core, Ant plugin, Console plugin, Eclipse plugin, Console plugin, JDeveloper plugin and Jedit plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Any Java IDE will have a way to reformat code.

A lot of "programmer-friendly" text editors have a "java mode" that supports code reformatting.

There are a few command-line Java indent / indenter tools around ... if you'd care to scan through the Google search results.  (Search for "java indenter tool" or "java formatter tool".)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse:

Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> edit -> Line Wrapping tab -> Set "Maximum line width" to 80 or some other limits